# How to generate a full linklist of a ftp server

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ftp, sh

How to generate a full linklist of a ftp server

For example:

```
/disk1/onfile.txt
/disk1/folder one/some Name.txt
/disk1/folder one/some Name2.txt
/disk1/folder one/some Name3.txt
/disk1/folder one/some Name4.txt
/disk1/folder one/any project name/file.doc
/disk1/folder one/any project name/file.doc
/disk1/folder one/any project name/file.doc
/disk1/folder one/any project name/file.doc
```

I need something like:

```
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/onfile.txt
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/some%20Name.txt
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/some%20Name2.txt
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/some%20Name3.txt
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/some%20Name4.txt
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/any%20project%20name/file.doc
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/any%20project%20name/file.doc
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/any%20project%20name/file.doc
ftp://192.168.0.1/disk1/folder%20one/any%20project%20name/file.doc
```

Its a huge amount of small files, and a slow server with interrupts, that make ist more complicated.
At the moment i use

```
lftp -e "find;quit" -u user,pass -p 21 ftp://192.168.0.1 > $temp_dir_txt/$host.txt
```

and do the rest with find and replace ... but thats a messy solution.

I played around with `wget --spider -r`, but without success and the spider function is not well documented.

I really hope someone knows a better solution.

Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: Sometimes servers calculate ls-R style index files and provide them for download. Some ftp server software even could do that on demand. On the other hand, the find solution you mentioned seems perfectly fine if the server allows it.

Comment: yes, `lftp ... | sed 's@^@ftp://192.168.0.1/@' > $temp_dir_txt/$host.txt` might do it for you. Good luck.